# Выравнивание блоков по ширине

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Доброго времени суток.
У меня вопрос по flex.
Есть родительский блок с display: flex, в нем 2 блока с display: flex и дочерние блоки.

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div 1a>text text texttext text text text text text text</div>
    <div 2a>text text</div>
    <div 3a>texttexttexttext text text</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div 1b>display display displaydisplaydisplaydisplay displaydisplaydisplaydisplaydisplay display display</div>
    <div 2b>display</div>
    <div 3b>display display</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы дочерние блоки равнялись по высоте как 1a = 1b, 2a = 2b, 3a = 3b, не зависимо он их содержимого?

Comment: По какой высоте?

Answer (score 0):

### Почему flex не вариант!?

Flexbox по определению не может создавать ряды с одинаковой высотой, одинаковую высоту можно получить только в одном ряду для всех элементов внутри него.

> **[Flexbox lines](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-lines)**
>
> > In a multi-line flex container, the cross size of each line is the
> >     minimum size necessary to contain the flex items on the line.

### Решение

В данном случае, я бы порекомендовал вам использовать `grid`, потому что это *очень эффективно* (за счет скорости и легкости написания) и *легко поддерживать*.

Можете убедиться сами.

### Пример

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa</div>
  <div class="child">asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa</div>
  <div class="child">asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa</div>
  <div class="child">dsadsadasdasdas asd das das das das das das</div>
  <div class="child">dsadsadasdasdas asd das das das das das das</div>
    <div class="child">asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa asddsa</div>
</div>
```

Comment: только забыли сказать что grid плохо поддерживается

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ну как посмотреть https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: статистика изменилась - сорри - но единственное наверно не у всех ещё современные браузеры ... и современные компы ...